# how to access function/class properties javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

In the following code, I am having trouble figuring out how to log (in the console) the `name` and `numLegs` properties of `Penguin` (i.e., "emperor" and 2), **without** changing the inside of the function?

```
function Penguin(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = 2;
}

var emperor = new Penguin("emperor");
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply accessing it's properties. Your emperor is an object, which means that you can access properties with `.` syntax.

```js
function Penguin(name){

   this.name=name;

   this.numLegs=2;

}

var emperor = new Penguin("emperor");

console.log(emperor.name);
console.log(emperor.numLegs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple function :

```
for (var key in emperor) {
  if (emperor.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + emperor[key]);
  }
}
```

or write

```
console.log(emperor.numLegs);
console.log(emperor.name);
```

Reference: [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)